# How can I prove that $\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\int_0^1(\cos\sqrt x)^n\,dx=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

I would like to prove  the following limit $$\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\int_0^1(\cos\sqrt x)^n\,dx=0.$$

I know that I can prove it simply using the dominated convergence theorem, but I want to see if there are other ways, involving less sophisticated tools (theorems from basic calculus).

Can someone help me? Any hint would be highly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yet another way:
\begin{align}
0&\le\int_0^1\cos^n\sqrt{x}\,dx=[t=\sqrt{x}]=2\int_0^1t\cos^nt\,dt=2\int_0^1\frac{t}{\sin t}\cdot\cos^nt\sin t\,dt\le\\
&\le\frac{2}{\sin 1}\int_0^1\cos^nt\sin t\,dt=\frac{2}{\sin 1}\left[-\frac{\cos^{n+1}t}{n+1}\right]_0^1=O\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)\to 0.
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

Try to show, for example, that $0\leq \cos(\sqrt{x})\leq 1-x/4$ on the interval. Then just integrate and squeeze.

Comment: Another estimation works nicely without binomial: $\cos t\le\exp(-t^2/2)$,
$$
\int_0^1\cos^n\sqrt{x}\,dx\le\int_0^1e^{-nx/2}\,dx\le\int_0^\infty e^{-nx/2}\,dx=\frac{2}{n}.
$$

Comment: @A.Γ. Thank you my friend. That is indeed more elegant. Frankly, I just took the 1/4 arbitrarily. I was a bit upset. Not with OP, but with his/her education. These kind of estimates should be very straight forward and natural, _before_ one even meet anything like dominated convergence.

Answer (score 1):

Pick $0 <a <1$. Then 
$$\int_0^1(\cos\sqrt x)^n\,dx\leq \int_0^a(\cos\sqrt x)^n\,dx+\int_a^1(\cos\sqrt x)^n\,dx\leq a+(1-a) \cos(\sqrt{a})^n$$

Now set $n \to \infty$ to get
$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1(\cos\sqrt x)^n\,dx\leq a$$
(you need to use limsup because you don't know that the limit exists).

Since this is true for all $a >0$, you can conclude that 
$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1(\cos\sqrt x)^n\,dx=0$$
from which the claim follows immediately.

Comment: This is the most straightforward way to understand what happens here.